# find all types that are instances of a typeclass

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, ghci

learnyouahaskell [mentions the following](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101):

Types in Enum class are

```
(), Bool, Char, Ordering, Int, Integer, Float and Double
```

Is there any way to find which types are instances of which typeclass and vice versa in GHCi?

I want something like the `:t` that we use in GHCi to find the type of a expression.

Answer (score 24):

Sure.

For a type class:

```
Prelude> :i Enum
class Enum a where
  succ :: a -> a
  pred :: a -> a
  toEnum :: Int -> a
  fromEnum :: a -> Int
  enumFrom :: a -> [a]
  enumFromThen :: a -> a -> [a]
  enumFromTo :: a -> a -> [a]
  enumFromThenTo :: a -> a -> a -> [a]
    -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Enum Ordering -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Enum Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Enum Int -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Enum Char -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Enum Bool -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Enum () -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Enum Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
instance Enum Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
```

For a type:

```
Prelude> :i Integer
data Integer
  = integer-gmp:GHC.Integer.Type.S# GHC.Prim.Int#
  | integer-gmp:GHC.Integer.Type.J# GHC.Prim.Int# GHC.Prim.ByteArray#
    -- Defined in `integer-gmp:GHC.Integer.Type'
instance Enum Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Eq Integer -- Defined in `integer-gmp:GHC.Integer.Type'
instance Integral Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
instance Num Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
instance Ord Integer -- Defined in `integer-gmp:GHC.Integer.Type'
instance Read Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Read'
instance Real Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
instance Show Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
instance Ix Integer -- Defined in `GHC.Arr'
```

Unfortunately, this is limited to identifiers, not expressions. So you can't look up, say, what instances apply to a type like `[Char]` directly.

Also, note that it will only show instances and types that are in scope, so you may need to import stuff you're curious about.